# What are some other alternatives to Win32 resource?

Tags: c++, windows, resources

This question applies to executables on Windows.
What are some alternative ways of storing data in an executable, then read it later at runtime.

I only know one, which is Win32 resources. Other options?
I honestly don't know how to search on this one, so sorry if this seems like a bad question.

Comment: Resources are the correct and preferred way of doing this. Why do you think you need to use something else?

Comment: I'm just exploring other possible options :) There is nothing wrong with Win32.

Comment: If you're writing a Windows application, it seems a bit futile or even nonsensical to try to get away from Win32. Unless there's something that resources won't do for you, then you should use them. There's a reason they're the recommended way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Structured Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380369%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may store the data in data files, or registries, and read it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

To store it *in* an executable, the other common way is an [NTFS Alternate data streams (ADS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29).

Comment: Alternate streams are removed from the upcoming new file system for Windows 8. Probably not the best long term approach.